# ClassCast Exception Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea, classcastexception

I am getting a ClassCastException in android studio while running my project. Can anyone tell me what is causing this error.

ClassCastException: com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiPlainTextFileImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile

Thanks.

Comment: what is your code???

Comment: Posting the code is not a problem for me. I dont know what is causing is exception. So i dont know which part of code to share. Can you please tell me what is causing this or what code i must share?

Comment: Are you running Android Studio for first time?

Comment: What version of `Android Studio` are you using?

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal . AndroidStudio 2.0 Preview

Comment: I think @KNeerajLal is on the right track. I didn't notice before, but that definitely looks like an internal error with Android Studio.

Comment: Use a stable version. I think its a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks @K Neeraj Lal . I will try and post the status here.

Comment: I tried with the latest stable version of Android studio. But got the same error

Comment: @David Then it seems like you've got a Resource file that your IDE thinks is plain text. Make sure they're all valid XML.

Comment: @Mike M. Yeah Mike. I migrated the project from eclipse to Android Studio. After that the when i try to open a xml file my Event Log shows this "ClassCastException: com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiPlainTextFileImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile". When i create a new project the xml is opening just fine. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @David Dunno. You might just have to manually copy and paste your XML files.

Comment: @Mike M. Ok Mike. Will give it a try.

Comment: @Mike M. Sovled this atlast. This Question helped me.Android Studio ClassCastException When Attempting to Open A Layout XML File . I had a 11MB xml file in values. That was the problem. After deleting that, the problem was solved

Comment: @David Cool. You might consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @Mike M. Posted Mike. Can you pls accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sovled this atlast. This Question helped me. [Android Studio ClassCastException When Attempting to Open A Layout XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414619/android-studio-classcastexception-when-attempting-to-open-a-layout-xml-file) . I had a 11MB xml file in values. That was the problem. After deleting that, the problem was solved.

And if you want to use a large XML file add the below code in idea.properties and vmoptions in the bin folder of Android Studio.

```
**Add in idea.properties**
 #-------------------------------------------------------------    --------
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE     should provide code assistance for.
# The larger file is the slower its.    editor works and higher overall system     memory requirements are
# if code assistance is enabled.     Remove this property or set to very.    large number if you need
# code assistance for any files     available regardless their size.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=999999


**Add in vmoptions**


-Didea.max.intellisense.filesize=999999     # <--- new line

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057988/file-size-exceeds-configured-limit-2560000-code-insightfeatures-not-availabl
```

Comment: How can I do this on mac os?

Comment: In Applications select android studio -> right click -> show contents. There you can edit .properties and .vmoptions

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can share some code snippets...

Anyways, as far as `ClassCastException` is concerned, it means you are declaring a variable of some type and assigning it to another type you have defined in a layout xml file...

for example, in the xml you may have had:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

but while connecting the component to code:

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView)context.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

This will fire a `ClassCastException` because you are casting a Button to an ImageView variable which is as you understand not possible!

If this doesn't solve your problem then it would be better if you post some code snippets after figuring out which code snippet causes the error!

Comment: .Thanks for answering. Posting the code is not a problem for me. I dont know what is causing is exception. So i dont know which part of code to share. Can you please tell me what is causing this or what code i must share?

Comment: This is the exception that is see.No line number nothing.ClassCastException: com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiPlainTextFileImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile. I Cant find the page, Can you?